# Getting error: [error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65 in ms app center while building

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to build my app on app center, but Achieve is getting failed, though I works locally on xcode.

The error is:
While  build getting this error: "xxxxx" requires a provisioning profile with the In-App Purchase and Push Notifications features. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'xxxxxx' from project 'xxxxxx')

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65

I did check that the provisioning profile has in-app purchase and push notification features added.

Can you please help me here? Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Yes. Restarting the xcode fixed it.